# Laravel 5 How to switch from Production mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

When I run `$ php artisan env` I get;

```
Current application environment: production
```

How can I change this to development or something similar? So I can see errors.. I have read [a lot of the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration) but it is not at all easy for a newbie to understand. I don't have server config experience, really.

I'm sure there is "smart" way to do this, but all I am interested in, for now, is manually changing the environment. How do I do this?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Laravel 5 gets its enviroment related variables from the [`.env`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example) file located in the root of your project. You just need to set `APP_ENV` to whatever you want, for example:

```
APP_ENV=development
```

This is used to identify the current enviroment. If you want to display errors, you'll need to enable debug mode in the same file:

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

The role of the `.env` file is to allow you to have different settings depending on which machine you are running your application. So on your production server, the `.env` file settings would be different from your local development enviroment.

Comment: So each server/environment has it's own `.env` file? Is that right?

Comment: You have one `.env` file, but the contents can differ on each machine you run the application. For example on your local machine you would have `APP_ENV=development` and `APP_DEBUG=true`, but on your production server the values would be `APP_ENV=production` and `APP_DEBUG=false`.

Comment: So yeah, each server/environment has it's own `.env` file.

Comment: @Bogdan In the case I use Composer, should I let the vendor folder in a production environment after set APP_ENV=production ?

Comment: @Zl3n Are you asking if you should deploy the `vendor` folder with the rest of your app or run a `composer install` on the production server?

Comment: @Bogdan Thank you for your quick answer ! So, use composer in local and deploy the whole project via FTP transfert (I haven't the rights to run composer on the server)

Comment: @Zl3n Yes, you can upload the whole project with no worries.

Comment: ... and yet, I have a .env in the root of my project with `APP_ENV=local` and yet `php artisan env` still tell me I'm in production mode..?

Answer (score 53):

Laravel 5 uses `.env` file to configure your app. `.env` should not be committed on your repository, like github or bitbucket. On your local environment your `.env` will look like the following:

```
# .env
APP_ENV=local
```

For your production server, you might have the following config:

```
# .env
APP_ENV=production
```

Answer (score 40):

Do not forget to run the command `php artisan config:clear` after you have made the changes to the .env file. Done this again `php artisan env`, which will return the correct version.

Comment: this will help anyone who find that the local server is trying to use `env.testing` after they have run tests

Answer (score 6):

What you could also have a look at is the exposed method `Application->loadEnvironmentFrom($file)`

I needed one application to run on multiple subdomains. So in `bootstrap/app.php` I added something like:

```
$envFile = '.env';
// change $envFile conditionally here
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom($envFile);
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question, but this is very useful. +1

Comment: Hacking core files is bad practice. These modifications will be lost after next updates

Answer (score -3):

In Laravel the default environment is always production.

What you need to do is to specify correct hostname in `bootstrap/start.php` for your enviroments eg.:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Detect The Application Environment
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Laravel takes a dead simple approach to your application environments
| so you can just specify a machine name for the host that matches a
| given environment, then we will automatically detect it for you.
|
*/

$env = $app->detectEnvironment(array(
    'local' => array('homestead'),
    'profile_1' => array('hostname_for_profile_1')
));
```

Comment: The question is for Laravel 5. Your solution is for Laravel 4. In L5 there's no `bootstrap/start.php` file anymore.